# running plotly.plotly.iplot() inside a funtion, no chart is shown

Tags: python, jupyter

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np

N = 500
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y
)


def myplot(data):
    print "ploting"
    py.iplot(data, filename='basic-line')

data = [trace]
myplot(data)

#py.iplot(data, filename='basic-line')
```

As the code shown above, if I use function myplot, no chart is shown. But if I use py.iplot directly, the chart is shown. Any body can help?

Comment: Please show your entire code, it has something to do with that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've updated the question, any ideas?

Comment: Please show your entire code in formatted text inside the question (like the pseudocode at the top of your question). Not as pictures, posting pictures is not very useful for the community. We cannot copy paste your code and run it for ourselves to see what is happening. I like helping people here but i am not going to retype what I see in a picture, I have other things to do. Also what you are showing is a for loop and not a function.

Comment: ok, I write a new demo about this.

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```